# How can I put Scroll glow in a sliverList instead of customScrollView?

Tags: flutter, customscrollview

The glow acts like the entire screen is a list. There some way that I can put the glow below the appbar? (edit: without losing the floating effect of the appbar)

[image: <code>**</code>enter image description here<code>**</code>]

```
CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text('Home Scree'),
          floating: true,
          leading: Icon(Icons.alarm),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (ctx, i) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ProductCard(),
                  Divider(
                    height: 0,
                    thickness: 1,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
            childCount: 10,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use `NestedScrollView`,like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [SliverAppBar(
            leading: Icon(Icons.alarm),
            title: Text('Home Scree'),
            expandedHeight: kToolbarHeight,
            floating: true,
          )];
        },
        body: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ProductCard(),
                  Divider(
                    height: 0,
                    thickness: 1,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: In that case I lose the "floating" effect of the app bar that disappear when scroll down.

Comment: @Denilson Maybe you can try to use `NestedScrollView`, I have updated my answer